# how to extract command name itself in shell script

Tags: shell, command-line, command

Let's say that I have the script named "test.sh".
I will run this script as

```
sh test.sh
```

Here I want the output as "sh test.sh" which is same as my command.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: when I print $0 i will get the script name but not the command. Quick reply will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
printf "%s\n" "$0" "$@"
```

to print full command line (each argument on separate line)

If you want to print it in single line then use:

```
printf "%s\n" "$0 $*"
```

Comment: No it did not work, it is still giving me only filename